# 3 level quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC app I have a peice of javscript that appends a row to a table.  The row is appneded using javascript (jquery).  Thestring that is added contains some mvc specific code as well.  I am having trouble getting the quotes and escapes correct.  I have tried several different combos, here is what i have:

```
var row = $("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='LocationArray' value='"
 + CellValue + "'>" + CellText +
 "</td><td class='delete' >" +
 "<img src='@Url.Content(\"~/Content/images/delete_x.png\")' /></td></tr>");
```

Comment: That looks valid to me .. are you getting any errors?

Comment: Not a problem with the syntax.. It should work..

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you want to be escaping the Razor string:

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/images/delete_x.png")
```

Remember, the Razor syntax gets parsed first.  This makes it clearer what's going on:

```
@{ var url = Url.Content("~/Content/images/delete_x.png"); }

var row = $("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='LocationArray' value='"
    + CellValue + "'>" + CellText +
    "</td><td class='delete' >" +
    "<img src='@url' /></td></tr>");
```

---

Footnote:  once you get to this level of dynamic HTML construction, it might be time to consider a client-side templating library (Underscore, Mustache, $.tmpl, etc).  Using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
<script type='text/template' id='the-template'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' name='LocationArray' value='<%= val %>' />
            <%= text %>
        </td>
        <td class='delete' >
           <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/delete_x.png");' />
        </td>
   </tr>
</script>

<script>
    var tmpl = _.template($("#the-template").html());
    var data = { val: "hello", text: "world" };
    var html = tmpl(data);
    $("#target").html(html);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should build your elements with jquery.

```
var el = $("<tr>")
  .append($("<td>")
    .append($("<input>")
    .attr({type: "hidden", name: "LocationArray"})
    .val(CellValue)
    .text(CellText)
  )
)
```

Etc, etc.. It's much clearer as to what you're trying to accomplish, and you will be able to catch errors and make changes much easier.